# Opensource projects using JIRA?

Tags: github, project-management, issue-tracking

For my master thesis in software engineering I am looking into opensource projects using JIRA as an issue tracking system. However, other than Jenkins and the projects by Apache, it seems that such projects are rare (or at least difficult to find). Does anyone know some other opensource (github) projects that use JIRA for their issue tracking?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's turning into a great example of why list-type questions aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow's Q&A format.

Comment: It's certainly a good example of why list-type questions that are never going to have an answer accepted are a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Sonatype**

Jira for Issues: https://issues.sonatype.org/
Nexus OSS: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public

2. **JFrog**

Jira for issues: https://www.jfrog.com/jira
Code on GitHub: https://github.com/jfrog

Answer (score 3):

The WildFly project uses both JIRA (https://issues.jboss.org/projects/WFLY/issues) and GitHub (https://github.com/wildfly )

Answer (score 1):

jfrog is another one, they have OSS projects on GitHub: https://github.com/jfrog

But they use Jira for issues: https://www.jfrog.com/jira

Answer (score 0):

[oVirt](https://ovirt.org/), an open source data center virtualization solution, uses [jira](https://ovirt-jira.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa), although, AFAIK, it is only for tracking issues around their own infrastructure (Jenkins builds, Gerrit code review, etc) and not for tracking issues/features in the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB**:

You can see MongoDB Jira [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DRIVERS-717?filter=-9)